# how to know if PHP server is installed on my computer

Tags: php

How can i know if PHP server is installed on my pc ?

and secondly i need a simple link where i can download it

with simple steps

```
<?php
?>
<?
?>
```

Regards

Comment: Echo something.. phpinfo(); or echo "hello world";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the .. emm ... structure of question, you are a primary OS is Windows. Instead of installing it on the existing system, you should consider using an virtualized server.

It is possible using [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to set up a server which runs on some distribution of linux or bsd. And it is possible to forward ports from the virtual OS to your localhost. This sort of solution also has the added benefit of simplifying the process of keeping it all up to date and it would give you a good reason for expanding you knowledge.

And then there is the fact, that you would not be polluting your main OS. You just turn the VM of, and its all gone. You have to also consider, that webserver might be accessible from outside. If you forget about having it , and there is a vulnerability found, it ming endanger your main OS. With virtual operating system there isn't such risk.

As "how" to know if you have server installed: check the task manager and the running services.

Answer (score 3):

> How can i know if PHP server is installed on my pc ?

Ask your system administrator. There are so many different servers that could support PHP, you'll have to ask someone who knows the machine you are dealing with.

> and secondly i need a simple link where i can download it

http://php.net/

PHP is usually used in combination with a separate webserver. [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) is one of the more popular choices.